# Targetting landscape tablet layout using layout-sw600dp-land with exclusion of nexus 5

Tags: android, layout, tablet, landscape, nexus-5

I'm trying to design a layout for android tablets (nexus 7 above) in landscape mode only - no phones
but when I use this xml filter layout-sw600dp-land the preview shows me nexus 5 and other phones are matching this filter too. 
How can I exclude phones from my filter (preferably not from java)